# SP - How to delete(clear) folders/items from doclib/list

Tags: list, document-library, splistitem, delete

I want to delete(clear) content of document libraries and lists from my site.

- my document libraries have folders and items inside them.
- my list have items

How to do this:

**This is my code:**

```
                 foreach (SPList list in fundListAndLibs)
                 {
                     if (list.BaseType == SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary)
                     {
                         foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)                           
                         {
                            ///I cannot delete folder with this             
                           //item.Folder.Delete();

                             //This delete only items in folders
                             item.File.Delete();    
                         }
                     }
                     if (list.BaseType == SPBaseType.GenericList)
                     {
                         foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
                         {
                             list.GetItemById(item.ID).Delete();
                         }
                     }
                 }
```

Comment: are you tried item.File.Delete(); within foreach of doc library

Comment: See my code ... Will it really work?

Comment: Please write this in response to accept it.

Comment: glad to hear it's worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete items within document library , try the following

```
foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
         {
            item.File.Delete();    
         }
       }
```

To delete folders with its subfolders and items, try the following

```
String siteURL = "http://Qassas";
                String docName = "Qassas";


                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteURL))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPFolderCollection folders = web.Folders[docName].SubFolders;

                        foreach (SPFolder folder in folders)
                        {
                            if (folder.Url != docName + "/Forms")
                            {
                                web.Folders[docName].SubFolders.Delete(folder.Url);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: This only delete items in folders, i want delete AND folders...

Comment: let me apply something in my side and come back to you :)

Comment: I have updated my answer , and sorry for late response because I was tried it first in my side , hope to help you :)

Comment: With this work fo me --> SPFolderCollection folders = web.Folders[web.Url + "/" + list.RootFolder.Url].SubFolders;